# Removing backslash escape for bash script in python

Tags: python, bash

I'm trying to run a bash expression in python but got really stuck at escape sequence.

*Bash expression:*

```
grep 'NODE_FW' /etc/config/node.py | cut -d ',' -f2,3 | tr ',' '.' | tr -d \'\"
```

*Python error:*

```
>>>> cmd = 'grep \'NODE_FW\' /etc/config/node.py | cut -d \',' -f2,3 | tr ',' '.' | tr -d \'\" 
  File "<stdin>", line 1
    cmd = 'grep \'NODE_FW\' /etc/config/node.py | cut -d \',' -f2,3 | tr ',' '.' | tr -d \'\" 
                                                                                         ^
SyntaxError: Unknown character
```

Tried using `r'\'` and `'\\'` but no luck.
Have checked almost all the links available over the web. Also, please don't suggest about third party modules. Any help please !

Comment: typo: you're opening the string using simple quote, and closing with double quote.

Comment: try ending by a quote: `...tr -d \'\"'` or better: use double quotes which will avoid the escaping of the single quotes in all the args

Comment: try that: `cmd = "grep 'NODE_FW' /etc/config/node.py | cut -d ',' -f2,3 | tr ',' '.' | tr -d \'\""`

Comment: problem is with your current expression it ends here: `'grep \'NODE_FW\' /etc/config/node.py | cut -d \','`

Comment: But why on earth would you call the `grep`, `cut`, and `tr` programs when you can do all that in python?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `raw` string using `r"..."`:

```
>>> cmd = r"grep 'NODE_FW' /etc/config/node.py | cut -d ',' -f2,3 | tr ',' '.' | tr -d \'\""
>>> print cmd
grep 'NODE_FW' /etc/config/node.py | cut -d ',' -f2,3 | tr ',' '.' | tr -d \'\"
```

Comment: also using double quotes avoids to escape the single quotes (which you don't need BTW for most commands since they don't contain spaces.

Comment: @anubhava Yes, it did work. Thanks for that. However, I was wondering if this applies to whatever expression you put inside as raw string. Because for me `grep 'NODE_FW' /etc/config/node.py | cut -d ',' -f2,3 | tr ',' '.' | tr -d '" > var && for i in $var; do echo 10.$i.1; done` fails.

Comment: In the appended code, there are no double quotes. It's just redirecting to a file and then concatenating some string in a for loop. I'm getting below error for err in p.communicate.

`/bin/sh: -c: line 0: unexpected EOF while looking for matching `''`
`/bin/sh: -c: line 1: syntax error: unexpected end of file`

Comment: You can try: `cmd = r"grep 'NODE_FW' /etc/config/node.py | cut -d ',' -f2,3 | tr ',' '.' | tr -d \'\" > var && for i in $var; do echo 10.$i.1; done"`